# How can I get a random distribution that "clusters" objects?

Tags: random

I'm working on a game, and I want to place some objects randomly throughout the world. However, I want the objects to be "clustered" in clumps. Is there any random distribution that clusters like this? Or is there some other technique I could use?

Comment: You'd have to define what you mean by "clusters" and "clumps".

Comment: @ScottHunter Something like this would suffice (ignore the k-means animation) http://shabal.in/visuals/kmeans/6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [bivariate normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivariate_normal) (a.k.a. Gaussian) distribution. Generate separate normal values for the X and Y location.  Bivariate normals are denser towards the center, sparser farther out, so your choice for the standard deviation of the distribution will determine how tight the clustering is - 2/3 of the items will be within 1 standard deviation of the distribution's center, 95% within 2 standard deviations, and almost all within 3 standard deviations.